# Is a Difference of Fiber Bundles a Fiber Bundle?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, fibre-bundles

I have a seemingly very basic question in differential topology, but I could not find the answer by a short google search.

Let $M,N$ be smooth manifolds, and let $f:M\to N$ be a smooth fiber-bundle,
namely locally $f$ is isomorphic to a projection from a direct product into one of the factors, in the smooth sense. 
Let $Z \subseteq M$ be a closed sub-manifold such that $f|_Z$ is a fiber bundle as well. Is it always true that $f|_{M\backslash Z}$ is also a fiber bundle map?

I guess it is true for for proper map $f$ because in this case we can "straighten" the embedding of $Z$ in $M$ locally over the fiber by some sort of "isotopy extension". My question is relevant only for the non-proper case I think, in which I know that isotopy extension fails in general, but the condition of $M\backslash Z$ being locally trivial seem weaker than a local trivialization of the pair $(M,Z)$, which if I understand correctly is exactly the meaning of isotopy extension for isotopy parametrized by the a small ball in the base $N$.

Comment: What if you take  $$f \colon  \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},$$
the projection on the first factor, and $Z = \{xy-1=0\}$? Here $f|_Z$ is a diffeomorphism of $Z$ onto $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$, hence surely a fiber bundle, but the restriction of $f$ to the complement submanifold is *not* a fiber bundle (for instance because all the fibres outside $0$ are $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$, but the fibre over $0$ is $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: This example leads me to think that a natural assumption to add (probably not sufficient in general) is that the restriction of $f$ to $Z$ must surject onto $N$.

Comment: The easiest counterexample should be to take for Z a finite set of points in pairwise different fibers.

Comment: I'm not sure if this works: Take $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^3$ with projection onto the first factor; and $Z$ is the graph of an infamous "fake" unknotting by pulling a knot tight, i.e., shrinking the knotted part of $Z$ to a point (this is not an ambient isotopy). See *The Knot Book* by Colin Adams, Figure 1.20. At each "time" $t$ (in the $\mathbb{R}$ factor) the fiber of $Z$ is an $S^1$. The fibers of $\mathbb{R}^3-Z$ have different fundamental groups.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think my $Z$ is a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^4$. At least, not in any way that I can think of.

Comment: @ZachTeitler Is is not, and indeed this example is compactifiable so problematic. However, if you assume that your knot is a long knot coming from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ and you stretch the knot and pull it to the "right" fast when approaching 0 this actually might work. Ill think about it thanks!

Comment: Why do you say that isotopy extension fails in general? I think that the answer to the question is "yes". I do not count Francesco Polizzi's example because I interpreted "$f|_Z$ is a fiber bundle" to mean that it is a fiber bundle with base $N$.

Comment: right, I also don't count this as fiber bundle. But what is the problem with the example of the long trefoil that run to infinity like $1/t$? ins't it a counter example at 0?